# Count frequency of timestamp by date and hour using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, frequency

I'm new using python and I have been looking for the answer, but nothing helps me.

I have a pandas data frame of the form

data

Out:

```
      CALL_TYPE   TIMESTAMP
 0           B    1408039037
 1           B    1408038611
 2           B    1408038568
 3           B    1408039090
 4           B    1408039177
 5           A    1408037146
 6           B    1408038846
 7           A    1408038948...
```

My **TIMESTAMP** is an **int64** of the type **pandas.core.series.Series**

I would like to count the frequency of my TIMESTAMP by "day" and "hour".

**How can I achieve this using Python pandas?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is your timestamp in hours or in seconds?

Comment: DYZ, It is in seconds.

Thanks.

Comment: Then see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, split them into hours and days:

```
data['DAY'], data['HOUR'] = data["TIMESTAMP"] // (24*3600), data["TIMESTAMP"] % (24*3600)
```

Now, do the count:

```
data.groupby(['DAY','HOUR']).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget
`datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)` can give your local time, as the `time.localtime(timestamp)` .

`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)` would give you UTC time.

(e.g.

```
data['HOUR'] = str(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data["TIMESTAMP"]))[11:13]
data['DAY'] = str(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(data["TIMESTAMP"]))[:10]
```

Then use groupby() for a correct time format.